# Error when using two react-select dropdown - how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

I am using the react-timezone (which is built on react-select) and a traditional react-select dropdown. When I use either one it's fine but when I use both in one form I am getting the following error:

```
   [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #react-select-3-input:
```

This id is generated in the DOM but it's not something that is specified in the jsx code. Speaking of code - here is my timezone code

```js
  <TimezoneSelect
              id="timezone-select"
              className="select-box"
              value={timezone}
              onChange={setTimezone}
              theme={(theme) => ({
                ...theme,
                borderRadius: 0,
                colors: {
                  ...theme.colors,
                  primary25: "#ecf1f5",
                  primary: "#0f4c81",
                },
              })}
            />
```

And my other react-select component

```js
 <Select
              id="select-num"
              className="select-box"
              options={options}
              value={value}
              onChange={setValue}
              theme={(theme) => ({
                ...theme,
                borderRadius: 0,
                colors: {
                  ...theme.colors,
                  primary25: "#ecf1f5",
                  primary: "#0f4c81",
                },
              })}
            />
```

I can't imagine you can't use two react-select dropdown elements in one form but can't seem to figure out how to use both without this error. Any ideas????? I'm totally stumped!

Comment: Can you provide the whole form code? React-select should generate unique ids for each select element. Try to verify which elements have the duplicate Id, open your browser and go to inspect element and search in your forms for the elements who have this `#react-select-3-input` id.